# How to stop running the app when you double tap the home button or go to the home page?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

[image]

How can I stop my game when I am on home or in the double click place, because my game continue and when I open it again I already lose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually much better policy to sign up for UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification:NSNotification) in
        self.pause()
    }
```

Otherwise you will need to get references to your UIApplicationMain, which is basically the wrong way to do things.  This is what NSNotificationCenter was made for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code to [applicationWillResignActive:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:) in your app delegate.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812269/pause-sprite-kit-scene-when-home-button-is-pressed?rq=1) also has some discussion on this topic.