# How to spawn SKSpriteNode when needed?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a several SKSpriteNodes in my SpriteKit game like backgrounds for pause and game over scenes and buttons for it. For now I'm declaring and adding them in `didMoveToView` and using things like:

```
let pauseButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pauseButton")
let pauseBackground = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "pauseBackground")
let resumeButton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "resumeButton")
```

Then, I'm initializing them:

```
self.pauseButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
self.pauseButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - self.cookieSpot / 3, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - self.cookieSpot / 3)
pauseButton.size = self.pauseButton.size
pauseButton.name = "pauseButton"
pauseButton.zPosition = 1000

pauseBackground.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
self.pauseBackground.hidden = true
self.pauseBackground.name = "pauseBackground"
self.pauseBackground.zPosition = +1
resumeButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + self.resumeButton.size.height * 2 + self.resumeButton.size.height - self.resumeButton.size.height / 4)
self.resumeButton.hidden = true
self.resumeButton.name = "resumeButton"
self.resumeButton.zPosition = +1
```

And then adding them:

```
self.addChild(pauseBackground)
self.addChild(resumeButton)
self.addChild(gameOverBackground)
```

when it's not needed and when user is tapping a pause button I'm trying to use things like this:

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
       switch self.nodeAtPoint(location) {
case pauseButton:
        self.pauseBackground.hidden = false
        self.resumeButton.hidden = false
        self.scene?.view?.paused = true
case resumeButton:
        self.pauseBackground.hidden = true
        self.resumeButton.hidden = true
        self.scene?.view?.paused = false
        default:
        println("not good")

   }
}
```

That's not working for me at all. They are spawning I guess, but they are invisible. How one should store that nodes when they're not needed and spawn them when it's the right time?

Comment: What do you mean by "spawning" ?

Comment: That should work. Maybe its something with initialization of the pause button? post it for us

Comment: @sangony I mean to present them above other nodes. Think of a pause scene that appearing on a screen when when user tap a button for example. For now I'm declaring it in a class, position them and do `addChild` in `didMoveToView` and set them to be hidden. Then, when user interacts with pause button I want them to appear above other nodes. I try `hidden = false` but they are still invisible. Although I can unpause the game if I'm clicking the spot where resume button should be.
@M321K I've updated my code now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding nodes is done at the end of [runloop](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-game-with-sprite-kit/game-loop-and-texture-atlas/understanding-the-game-run-loop) and you are pausing the view before that...I guess the problem is related to that (tested it and I got same results). In Obj-C an easy workaround would be using the [performSelector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) method like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612551/3402095). In Swift it get trickier an you should probably use something like [dispatch_after](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170785/3402095) or go with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170823/3402095) ( using NSTimer ). Hope this helps a bit. Also this is not an definitive answer, and probably there are more solutions for the same problem.

EDIT:

I just found workable [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826890/3402095) ( pausing is moved inside some method ):

```
func pauseGame()
   {
         self.scene?.view?.paused = true
   }
```

And then call it in touchesBegan

```
 self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock(self.pauseGame))
```

Your touchesBegan should probably look like this:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            switch self.nodeAtPoint(location) {
            case pauseButton:
                self.pauseBackground.hidden = false
                self.resumeButton.hidden = false

               self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock(self.pauseGame))
            case resumeButton:
                self.pauseBackground.hidden = true
                self.resumeButton.hidden = true
                self.scene?.view?.paused = false
            default:
                println("not good")

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's great! Let me make it clear if I understood you right. Do you suggest to call pause SKAction after  `self.pauseBackground.hidden = false`
        `self.resumeButton.hidden = false` in my switch statement? Or I should rewrite all touchesBegan function?

Comment: Just try to call self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock(self.pauseGame)) instead of self.scene?.view?.paused = true ... It should work(works for me).

Comment: Yes! It totally worked! I Thank you @Whirlwind! At last I can go further with it :D